# Javascript DateTimePicker create timespan array with 15 minute intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I am using this date time picker https://github.com/Envek/jquery-datetimepicker-rails ruby on my rails project. It's pretty good and things are working nice. However the time picker defaults to times on the hour. It would be nice to be able to have the time with 15 minute intervals eg [15:00, 15:15, 15:30, 15:45, 16:00 etc]. There doesn't seem to be a setting available that allows this. How would I programatically produce these times using javascript? or is there a setting which would allow me to do this in a much cleaner way?

Many Thanks,

Comment: It looks like the `step` option might be what you need - try setting it to 15:  http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker

Comment: hey man thanks for the pointer, should have seen this. want to wrtie the answer so i can give you the tick?